# Ruby how to iterate a collection and create a hash key if none exists, or add to the value if key does exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style

This is a pattern that I find myself using a lot and I am wondering if there is something in the built-in library that does this without adding all these control flow statements.  what I have is:

```
input = <<TEXT
/us/programming/sports:model.channel.tnt.name
/us/programming/sports:model.channel.spice.name
/us/programming/sports:model.classificationwebgenre.us-entertainment.programming_link_text
/international-sports/package:model.language.international-sports.name
/brazilian/programming/sports:model.package.hbo-extra.description
TEXT


def self.create_hash(text)
  output = {}
  text.each_line("\n") do |line|
    split_lines = line.split(":")
    if output.has_key?(split_lines.first)
      output[split_lines.first] << split_lines[1][0..-2]
    else
      output[split_lines.first] = [split_lines[1][0..-2]]
    end
  end
  output
end
```

end

also the output of this is:

```
{
      "/us/programming/sports" => ["model.channel.tnt.name", "model.channel.spice.name", "model.classificationwebgenre.us-entertainment.programming_link_text"],
      "/international-sports/package" => ["model.language.international-sports.name"],
      "/brazilian/programming/sports" => ["model.package.hbo-extra.description"]
    }
```

Am I just overcomplicating things with they way I am writing this?  Is there an idiomatic way to write this in ruby?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use a hash with a default value of an empty array.

Comment: I know what you mean by default value (output = Hash.new([])).  But then how would I assign the values to it, and have keys be created.  Sorry if this is a noob question(see username).

Comment: `the_hash[some_key] << some_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if is faster, but it's cleaner

```
def self.create_hash(text)
  output = {}
  text.each_line("\n") do |line|
    split_lines = line.split(":")
    output[split_lines.first] ||= []
    output[split_lines.first] << split_lines[1][0..-2]
  end
  output
end
```

Answer (score 1):

just define `output` with defaults:

```
output = Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] }
```

That would turn your code into:

```
def self.create_hash(text)
  output = Hash.new { |k, v| k[v] = [] }
  text.each_line("\n") do |line|
    split_lines = line.split(":")
    output[split_lines.first] << split_lines[1][0..-2]
  end
  output
end
```

Comment: While both of these solutions work, I marked letz's solution as correct because I feel like it is more explicit and because he can use the rep a little more.  Thank you for your input and If I could give you more than one upvote I would.